# Gradle test fails with NullPointerException

Tags: groovy, junit, gradle

I get this error when I run `gradle test`:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate test report to '/home/tjwebb/workspace/MyProject/build/reports/tests'.
```

Groovy 1.7.10
Gradle 1.0-m3

The weird thing is that my tests compile and run perfectly, they pass, and I get the usual output in `build/reports/tests`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace (`-s`). I also recommend to update to a more recent version of Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this was a bug. I upgraded to gradle 1.0-m9 and it works. For some reason,  `m3` is the version still in the Ubuntu repositories.