# Installing Gradle on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, classpath, gradle, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install Gradle on Ubuntu 12.04. At first I used the package in the repository, but after hitting [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/S4-18) [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066309/gradle-test-fails-with-nullpointerexception) it turned out I'd better use a more recent version.

I have removed the built-in package and installed gradle by copying the official 1.0 package into the `/usr/local/share/` directory and adding a soft link from `/usr/local/bin/gradle/` to `/usr/local/share/gradle-1.0/bin/gradle`.

It appears to work, but I run into a classpath problem. Namely as soon as I try to build a project I get

```
Exception executing org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler@1ab95774 in compiler daemon: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
```

Now `locate commons-cli.jar` gives me

```
/usr/share/groovy/lib/commons-cli.jar
/usr/share/java/commons-cli.jar
```

Apparently those two JARs are not on the classpath. Normally I would run a Java executable with the `-cp` options to add stuff to the classpath. But the gradle executable itself is a script that sets the classpath on its own before calling Java.

> What is the correct way to install Gradle and make it find everything that needs on its classpath?

Please, note that I am a complete newbie to the JVM world, so do not assume I am familiar with anything :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be enough to put

```
groovy group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.0'
```

under dependencies

Answer (score 0):

How to install Gradle in linux

Download Grade from 
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-all.zip

A simple old school rule to set up:

Extract is to /usr/local/

Add the path in to /etc/bash.bashrc

GRADLE_HOME=/usr/local/gradle-2.2.1
export GRADLE_HOME